# porque tengo que dar doble click para que se muestre el resultado de la función javascript con html

Tags: javascript, html5

Código javascript

```
 function mostrar(){
var rut= document.getElementById("rut").value;
var nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
var LAnterior=document.getElementById("LAnterior").value;
var direccion=document.getElementById("direccion").value;
var LActual=document.getElementById("LActual").value;
var comuna=document.getElementById("comuna").value;
var lista = document.getElementById("tipificacion");
var valor = lista.options[lista.selectedIndex].text;
tipificacion(valor);
     }


function tipificacion(valorSeleccionado){
    var ConsumoAnterior;
    var FechaPago;
    var MesPago;


    if (valorSeleccionado == "1a")
    {
    ConsumoAnterior=2;
   FechaPago="15-03-11"
     MesPago=3;
     document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = "Mes de pago:"+MesPago;
    }
   else if (valorSeleccionado =="1d" ){

     ConsumoAnterior=200;
     FechaPago="22-04-11"
      MesPago=4;
    }
    else if (valorSeleccionado =="1c"){
        ConsumoAnterior=5;
        FechaPago="29-05-11"
         MesPago=5;

    }else{
        alert("No a Ingresado tipificacion!")
    }


  }
```

codigo html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <form >


<table>
    <h2>Boleta Chilectra</h2>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>Rut</td>
             <td> <input type="text" name="rut" id="rut" value="" required>  
            </td>
             <td>Tipificacion</td>
             <td>
                  <select name="tipificacion" id="tipificacion" required>
                  <option value="1a">1a</option>
                  <option value="1d">1d</option>
                  <option value="1c">1c</option>
                   </select>  
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>Nombre Cliente</td>
              <td> <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" 
                required>  </td>
              <td>Lectura Anterior (KW)</td>
             <td> <input type="number" name="LAnterior" id="LAnterior"  
         min="50" required max="999999999999" > </td>
         </tr>   
         <tr>
                <td>Direccion</td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="direccion"  id="direccion" 
         required >  </td>
                <td>Lectura Actual(KW)</td>
               <td><input type="number" name="LActual" id="LActual"  
      required min="50" max="999999999999" > </td>
         </tr>   
         <tr>
                <td>Comuna</td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="comuna" id="comuna" value="" 
   required>  </td>
                <td>Lectura Actual(KW)</td>

         </tr>   


    </tbody>
   </table>

 <input type="submit" onclick="mostrar()" value="Enviar">


 <section id="Detalle boleta">
  <h2>Detalle Boleta</h2>
  <div id=contenerdor>

 </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Fecha de pago:</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Valor UF a la fecha:</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


 </section>
 <div id="c" name ="c"></div>
  <section id ="Consumo">
   <h2>Consumo de KW</h2>
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Consumo Actual (KW):</td>

            <td id="consumoac"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Consumo Anterior (KW):</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
      </section>
  <section id="Valor">
    <h2>Valor a Pagar</h2>
  Total: 
     </section>



   </form>
     </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 function mostrar() {
     var rut = document.querySelector("#rut"),
         nombre = document.querySelector("#nombre"),
         LAnterior = document.querySelector("#LAnterior"),
         direccion = document.querySelector("#direccion"),
         LActual = document.querySelector("#LActual"),
         comuna = document.querySelector("#comuna"),
         lista = document.querySelector("#tipificacion"),
         valor = lista.options[lista.selectedIndex].value;
     if (rut.value.length == 0) {
         alert('Debe rellenar el campo Rut.');
         rut.focus();
     } else if (nombre.value.length == 0) {
         alert('Debe rellenar el campo Nombre.');
         nombre.focus();
     } else if (direccion.value.length == 0) {
         alert('Debe rellenar el campo Direccion.');
         direccion.focus();
     } else if (comuna.value.length == 0) {
         alert('Debe rellenar el campo Comuna.');
         comuna.focus();
     } else if (LAnterior.value < 50 || LAnterior.value > 999999999999) {
         alert('Debe rellenar el campo Lectura Anterior.\nDebe ser entre 50 a 999999999999');
         LAnterior.focus();
     } else if (isNaN(LAnterior.value)) {
         alert('El campo Lectura Anterior solo acepta Numeros.');
         LAnterior.focus();
     } else if (LActual.value < 50 || LActual.value > 999999999999) {
         alert('Debe rellenar el campo Lectura Actual.\nDebe ser entre 50 a 999999999999');
         LActual.focus();
     } else {
         alert('Enviado Exitosamente');
         //ELIJE UNO U OTRO QUE ES LO QUE QUIERES HACER, SI MOSTRAR ABAJO CON LA FUNCION TIPIFICACION O ENVIARLO MEDIANTE GET POR EL FORMULARIO
         // nombre.closest('form').submit();
         //  tipificacion(valor);
     }
     // console.log(valor);
 }

 function tipificacion(valorSeleccionado) {
     var ConsumoAnterior, FechaPago, MesPago;
     if (valorSeleccionado == "1a") {
         ConsumoAnterior = 2;
         FechaPago = "15-03-11"
         MesPago = 3;
         document.querySelector('#c').innerHTML = "Mes de pago:" + MesPago;
     } else if (valorSeleccionado == "1d") {
         ConsumoAnterior = 200;
         FechaPago = "22-04-11"
         MesPago = 4;
     } else if (valorSeleccionado == "1c") {
         ConsumoAnterior = 5;
         FechaPago = "29-05-11"
         MesPago = 5;
     } else {
         alert("No a Ingresado tipificacion!")
     }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script src="1.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script>
        </meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <h2>
                    Boleta Chilectra
                </h2>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Rut
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="rut" name="rut" required="" type="text" value="">
                            </input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Tipificacion
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="tipificacion" name="tipificacion" required="">
                                <option value="1a">
                                    1a
                                </option>
                                <option value="1d">
                                    1d
                                </option>
                                <option value="1c">
                                    1c
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Nombre Cliente
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="nombre" name="nombre" required="" type="text" value="">
                            </input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Lectura Anterior (KW)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="LAnterior" max="999999999999" min="50" name="LAnterior" required="" type="number">
                            </input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Direccion
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="direccion" name="direccion" required="" type="text">
                            </input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Lectura Actual(KW)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="LActual" max="999999999999" min="50" name="LActual" required="" type="number">
                            </input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Comuna
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="comuna" name="comuna" required="" type="text" value="">
                            </input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Lectura Actual(KW)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input onclick="mostrar()" type="button" value="Enviar">
                <section id="Detalle boleta">
                    <h2>
                        Detalle Boleta
                    </h2>
                    <div id="contenerdor">
                    </div>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Fecha de pago:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Valor UF a la fecha:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </section>
                <div id="c" name="c">
                </div>
                <section id="Consumo">
                    <h2>
                        Consumo de KW
                    </h2>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Consumo Actual (KW):
                                </td>
                                <td id="consumoac">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Consumo Anterior (KW):
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </section>
                <section id="Valor">
                    <h2>
                        Valor a Pagar
                    </h2>
                    Total:
                </section>
            </input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```